# Humidity data in the US

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial, weather

Does anyone know where we can find daily/monthly humidity data at zipcode/county/state level?

Comment: do you need a bulk dataset or humidity measurements for a handful of locations?

Comment: try climate.gov and/or weather.gov

Comment: @philshem I am looking for a bulk dataset.